#  Are DLC codes region free?

Tags: mass-effect-3

My friend just got a copy of Mass Effect 3 in Europe, and it came with a bunch of bonus  DLC that we don't have in North America. He said I could have the codes since he isn't going to bother with them.

Will the codes work for my American version? Or are they region locked?

Comment: It may be worth mentioning what platform you're on, as I imagine PC Origin codes *may* be less likely to be region-locked than console ones.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb (applies in most cases):

PC DLC codes *should* be region free.

Console DLC codes are *almost never* region free.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. At Play Asia they say the collectors' edition is region free, which means all the codes are region free too.

Comment: Er, no, it doesn't mean that at all.